# How to remove page name and page number? In auto generate PDF Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using app script to do auto generate PDF in spreadsheet.
But when I execute the code, the result is automatically adding page name on left-top corner and page number on left-down corner.
Is it possible to remove the page name and and page number?

Here is the result:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
function createblobpdf(sheetName, pdfName) {
var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IaKnN8GIaLLyNZBMNBKTvml5V1pBzUjXx60BH_bKEdw/edit#gid=1194998923");
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("PAGENAME");
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + sourceSpreadsheet.getId() + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    +    '&size=A4' // paper size legal / letter / A4
    +    '&portrait=true' // orientation, false for landscape
    +    '&fitw=true' // fit to page width, false for actual size
    +    '&sheetnames=true&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
    +    '&pagenum=RIGHT&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
    +    '&fzr=false' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    +    '&horizontal_alignment=CENTER' //LEFT/CENTER/RIGHT
    +    '&vertical_alignment=TOP' //TOP/MIDDLE/BOTTOM
    +    '&gid=' + sourceSheet.getSheetId(); // the sheet's Id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to set the following two parameters:

- pagenumbers = false
- sheetnames = false

```
function createblobpdf(sheetName, pdfName) {
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IaKnN8GIaLLyNZBMNBKTvml5V1pBzUjXx60BH_bKEdw/edit#gid=1194998923");
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("PAGENAME");
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/' + sourceSpreadsheet.getId() + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    +    '&size=A4' // paper size legal / letter / A4
    +    '&portrait=true' // orientation, false for landscape
    +    '&fitw=true' // fit to page width, false for actual size
    +    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
    +    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
    +    '&fzr=false' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    +    '&horizontal_alignment=CENTER' //LEFT/CENTER/RIGHT
    +    '&vertical_alignment=TOP' //TOP/MIDDLE/BOTTOM
    +    '&gid=' + sourceSheet.getSheetId(); // the sheet's Id
  console.log(url);
}
```